# rxjs ForkJoin but have it complete when 1 of 2 observables give a value

Tags: rxjs

I'm new to rsjx but I'm looking for a solution like the Forkjoin but it should complete when 1 of the 2 observables have a value. It needs to be like a ForkJoin because I need to know which observable got a value.

example:
I'm loading categories and I have an autocomplete. Categories is an observable and the valueChanges is returned as an observable.

```
@Select(IngredientCategoryState.selectIngredientCategories) ingredientCategories$!: Observable<IngredientCategory[]>;

this.filter = this.ingredientForm.controls['category'].valueChanges.pipe(
  map((data) => {
    if (typeof data === 'object') {
      return data.name;
    }
    return data;
  })
)
```

Then I used the forkJoin but then it requires both observables to have a value

```
this.filteredIngredientCategories$ = forkJoin({
  ingredientCategories: this.ingredientCategories$,
  filter: this.filter
}).pipe(
  map(({ ingredientCategories, filter }) => {
    return this._filter(ingredientCategories, filter);
  })
);
```

UPDATE

I solved it with a combineLatest and triggering the autocomplete field

```
 combineLatest([this.ingredientCategories$, this.filter$])
  .pipe(
    map((data) => {
      return this._filter(data[0], data[1]);
    })
  ).subscribe((ingredientCategories) => {
  this.filteredIngredientCategories = ingredientCategories;
});

this.ingredientForm.controls['category'].setValue('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`race`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race) to use the first source to emit.

> I need to know which observable got a value

Instead of "knowing" which one emitted, you can transform the output of each source to return the object shape you need:

```js
this.filteredIngredientCategories$ = race(
  this.ingredientCategories$.pipe(
    map(ingredientCategories => ({ ingredientCategories, filter: undefined }))
  ),
  this.filter.pipe(
    map(filter => ({ filter, ingredientCategories: undefined }))
  )
).pipe(
  map(({ ingredientCategories, filter }) => {
    return this._filter(ingredientCategories, filter);
  })
);
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67218793?file=index.ts) demo.